# Xcode / Swift | Knowing if a UISwitch is turned on at any time

Tags: swift, xcode, uiswitch

Basically, what we got right now is a button that changes its colors (gray & green) based on if the TextFields are filled out or not... Now I would like to add a switch that also has to be switched on to let the button color change to green and change back to gray if not.
How exactly do I implement this part?
PS: setupAddTargetIsNotEmptyTextFields() is called within the viewDidLoad()

```
func setupAddTargetIsNotEmptyTextFields() {
    self.textField_username.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty), for: .editingChanged)
    self.textField_eMail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty),
        for: .editingChanged)
    self.textField_password.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty), for: .editingChanged)
    self.textField_confirmPassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty),
        for: .editingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldsIsNotEmpty(sender: UITextField) {

    sender.text = sender.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    guard
        let username = self.textField_username.text, !username.isEmpty,
        let eMail = self.textField_eMail.text, !eMail.isEmpty,
        let password = self.textField_password.text, !password.isEmpty,
        let confirmPassword = self.textField_confirmPassword.text,
        password == confirmPassword
        else
    {
        //button is gray
        self.button_register.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.29, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)
        return
    }
    //button is green
    self.button_register.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.74, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You're already checking a series of conditions to figure out whether the button can be enabled, so why not add the state of the switch to that list?

Comment: @Caleb When I just add the switch to the list, I first type in everything in the textFields and then enable the switch. At this moment the button is still gray. Then I have to first change something again in the textfields to make it work...

Comment: @Caleb So I added self.switch_aGB.addTarget(self.... to the method and also wrote "let switch_aGB = self.switch_aGB, switch_aGB.isOn == true" to the guard...What happens now is that everytime I try to hit the switch, the simulator dies and comes up with the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in the AppDelegate and the error message: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)"

Comment: I notice that `textFieldsIsNotEmpty()` expects the `sender` to be a text field, so passing in a switch without some modification there could be a problem (every control passes itself when it sends its action message). You could change it so that the type of `sender` is a `UIControl`, and then consider the specific type inside the method.

Comment: @Caleb Works now! I told the sender in the TextFieldIsNotEmpty method to be "any" and then just added the guard that  switch.isOn == true. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

> When I just add the switch to the list, I first type in everything in the textFields and then enable the switch. At this moment the button is still gray. Then I have to first change something again in the textfields to make it work.

It sounds like what's happening is that the switch isn't set to trigger the `textFieldsIsNotEmpty` action the way the text fields are. You can fix that easily enough: just configure the switch to call the action too:

```
func setupAddTargetIsNotEmptyTextFields() {
    self.textField_username.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty), for: .editingChanged)
    // ...yada yada yada...        
    self.switch_selfDestructEnable.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Now the switch will send a `textFieldsIsNotEmpty` when it's value changes just like the text fields do. Next, modify `textFieldsIsNotEmpty()` to check the state of the switch along with the state of the various text fields, and you should get the behavior you want.